# How to split a STL into surfaces in VTK

Tags: vtk, paraview

Can anybody know how to split an STL into surfaces in VTK? Or how to do it in Paraview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on how you want to split it. If you want to split it into grouped surfaces, use vtkPolyDataNormals with SplittingOn, and use SetFeatureAngle to decide what angle to split at. Then, you can use vtkPolyDataConnectivityFilter to get each split piece in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

In ParaView :

- Open ParaView
- File -> Open -> Select your STL file, Apply
- You obtain a single vtkPolyData object, you can then use ParaView for any splliting you may want to do.

In VTK :

```
vtkNew<vtkSTLReader> reader;
reader->SetFileName("/path/to/your/file.stl");
reader->Update()
```

You can the use reader output and show it or split it to your needs using VTK filters.